# WCF Service Throttling settings

Tags: performance, wcf

Can anyone point to some good articles on WCF Service Throttling settings to improve performance. I have a per call service with approx 100 users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about these?

- [MSDN: Using ServiceThrottlingBehavior to Control WCF Service Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735114.aspx)
- [KennyW: Throttling in WCF](http://kennyw.com/?p=150)
- [Dan Rigsby: How to throttle a WCF service](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/02/20/how-to-throttle-a-wcf-service-help-prevent-dos-attacks-and-maintain-wcf-scalability/)

You say approx. 100 users - but how many requests will those users send per hour/minute/second, and how long does your service take to service on request (on average)?

Marc